# Powershell close .msg after reading the body

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to read the Body of the email file (.msg) in a powershell script, however I can only open it once because the file is "locked" or already opened, so there is an error the 2nd time.

My Code:

```
Get-ChildItem $scriptPath -Filter *.msg |
ForEach-Object {
    $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
    $msg | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Body
    $outlook.Quit()
}
```

Error is: The file XXX cant be opened. Maybe it is already opened....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old thread, but its the top when searching for this issue. This is what worked for me:

```
Get-ChildItem $scriptPath -Filter *.msg |
ForEach-Object {
    $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
    $msg | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Body
    $msg.Close(1) # oldispose
    $msg = $null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Outlook version do you use?

There's [a bug in Outlook](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3a15a6bf-dfb9-48a7-9ee8-faf592bd1287/we-cant-open-filelocationmsg-its-possible-the-file-is-already-open-or-you-dont-have?forum=outlook) and a workaround is to mark the `.msg` files with `readonly` attribute.

Comment: I'm using Outlook 2013. This is only a .msg file.

Comment: Yes but didnt help